# jquery mouseleave .fadeOut but not! if mouse moves to specific DIV

Tags: jquery, parent-child, show, fadeout, mouseleave

I have a `mouseenter` on my trigger DIV with class="b6" witch does `fadeIn` on element ID="6" <- That works flawless!

Now I want my nonchild element ID="6" to `fadeOut` when `mouseleave` my trigger DIV - but not if mouse is moved to my newly faded in element with ID="6". In that case ID="6" should still be `.show`

Tried with making af variable but no luck..

Look at my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5L14xoq8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check if div is(':hover'), try this:

```
$("#6").hide();

$(".b6").mouseenter(function () {

    $("#6").fadeIn();

    });


$(".b6").mouseleave(function () {
    if($('#6').is(':hover') === false)
    {
        $("#6").fadeOut();
    }
});

$("#6").mouseleave(function () {
    if($('.b6').is(':hover') === false)
    {
        $("#6").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: At least in the lab ;) Have a little trouble with overlapping empty DIVs and z-index - but think I will sort that out.